# character level bidirectional language model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, language-model

Inspired from Andrej Karpathy Char-RNN, There is a Tensorflow implementation of char-rnn [sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow: Multi-layer Recurrent Neural Networks (LSTM, RNN) for character-level language models in Python using Tensorflow](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow). I want to implement bidirectional character level language model from this code. I change the [model.py](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py) and wrote a simple code:

```
class Model:
def __init__(self, input_data, targets, seq_length=Config.max_seq_length, training=True):
    if Config.model == 'rnn':
        cell_fn = rnn.BasicRNNCell
    elif Config.model == 'gru':
        cell_fn = rnn.GRUCell
    elif Config.model == 'lstm':
        cell_fn = rnn.BasicLSTMCell
    elif Config.model == 'nas':
        cell_fn = rnn.NASCell
    else:
        raise Exception("model type not supported: {}".format(Config.model))

    fw_cells = []
    bw_cells = []
    for _ in range(Config.num_layers):
        fw_cell = cell_fn(Config.rnn_size)
        bw_cell = cell_fn(Config.rnn_size)
        fw_cells.append(fw_cell)
        bw_cells.append(bw_cell)

    self.fw_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell(fw_cells, state_is_tuple=True)
    self.bw_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell(bw_cells, state_is_tuple=True)

    self.input_data, self.targets = input_data, targets

    with tf.variable_scope('rnnlm'):
        softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [Config.rnn_size*2, Config.vocab_size])
        softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [Config.vocab_size])

    embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [Config.vocab_size, Config.rnn_size])
    inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.input_data)

    inputs = tf.unstack(inputs, num=seq_length, axis=1)

    outputs, _, _ = tf.nn.static_bidirectional_rnn(self.fw_cell, self.bw_cell, inputs,
                                                   dtype=tf.float32, scope='rnnlm')
    output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(outputs, 1), [-1, Config.rnn_size*2])

    self.logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
    self.probs = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits)

    self.lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)

    if training:
        loss = legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example(
                [self.logits],
                [tf.reshape(self.targets, [-1])],
                [tf.sign(tf.cast(tf.reshape(self.targets, [-1]), dtype=tf.float32))])
        with tf.name_scope('cost'):
            self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
        grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars), Config.grad_clip)

        with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr)
        self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))
```

In training phase, I see a fast converge. After near 3000 iteration, the loss reach 0.003. In test phase, the probability of all character is 1.0. I think there is a mistake.
I will so glad to get some help to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the preceding and following output to predict the prob of current word. In your case, you used current rnn output to predict the prob of current word.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set `self.lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)`. Try changing this to a nonzero value. If you are reading probabilities from `self.probs` during the testing phase this should be normalized appropriately,